# Find the derivative of the function $f(x)=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-y^2-(x/y)^2} dy$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This problem confuses me, Can we use Leibniz  rule here? But in the chapter Leibniz rule was not introduced. Is it possible to find the derivative using simple concepts. The actual problem is to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-y^2-(9/y)^2} dy$ using differential equations.

Comment: You don't need Leibniz' rule. You just need to justify that you may differentiate under the integral.

Comment: If the problem is specifically asking for a solution using DEs, then I believe you need to use differentiation under integral sign. (Just for information, the integral can be tackled without DEs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct first step in evaluating $\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2-(9/y)^2}\,\mathrm{d}y$.

To justify the swapping of the order of integration and differentiation (differentiation inside the integral), we can use Fubini and FTC:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2-x^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^\infty\int_x^\infty\frac{2t}{y^2}e^{-y^2-t^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_x^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{2t}{y^2}e^{-y^2-t^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1b}\\
&=-\int_0^\infty\frac{2x}{y^2}e^{-y^2-x^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a)}$: $\int_x^\infty\frac{2t}{y^2}e^{-t^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=e^{-x^2/y^2}$
$\phantom{\text{(1a):}}$ here we are writing a function
$\phantom{\text{(1a):}}$ as the integral of its derivative
$\text{(1b)}$: [Fubini-Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)
$\text{(1c)}$: [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

---

**Hint 1:**

For the next step, you might want to complete the square in the exponents
$$
f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2-x^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y=e^{-2x}\int_0^\infty e^{-(y-x/y)^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag2
$$
and from $(1)$
$$
-\frac12f'(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{y^2}\,e^{-y^2-x^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y=e^{-2x}\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{y^2}e^{-(y-x/y)^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag3
$$
then consider the substitution $u=y-x/y$.

---

**Hint 2:**

Another approach to the next step was suggested by Sangchul Lee: note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2-x^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y
&=-\int_0^\infty\frac{2x}{y^2}e^{-y^2-x^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{4a}\\
&=-2\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2-x^2/y^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\tag{4b}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: $(1)$ allows us to differentiate inside the integral
$\text{(4b)}$: substitute $y\mapsto x/y$

and $(4)$ says that $f'(x)=-2f(x)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee: thanks, I have fixed the typo. Mentioning that $f'(x)=-2f(x)$ leads to  $f(x)=Ce^{-2x}$, but $C$ is not directly computable. The hint, hopefully, leads them to a way to evaluate the integral (at least the way that I evaluated the integral :-).

Comment: That comment makes sense, especially thinking that we don't know yet if OP is aware of the gaussian integral. :)

Comment: @SangchulLee: I am sorry, $C=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$ by setting $x=0$. So your earlier suggestion was on point.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very unusual problem indeed, especially since solving with a differential equation would probably be overkill. One easy solution is to do the following:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y^{2}-\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}} dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(y^{2}+\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}\right)} dy $$

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(y^{2}+\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}\right)} dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(y^{2}-2x+\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}+2x\right)} dy $$

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(y^{2}-2x+\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}+2x\right)} dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2x-\left(y^{2}-2x+\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}\right)} dy $$

And since we are integrating with respect to y only...

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2x-\left(y^{2}-2x+\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}\right)} dy = e^{-2x} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(y^{2}-2x+\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}\right)} dy $$

$$ e^{-2x} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(y^{2}-2x+\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}\right)} dy = e^{-2x} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(y-\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}} dy $$

Now I'm gonna write the whole thing a bit weirdly, but you'll understand where I'm going in a second:

$$ e^{-2x} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(y-\dfrac{x}{y}\right)^{2}} dy = e^{-2x} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(1\cdot y-xy^{-1}\right)^{2}} dy $$

According to the Cauchy-Schlömilch transformation, we can assume the following:

$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(\left(ax-bx^{-1}\right)^{2}) dx = \dfrac{1}{a} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x^{2}) dx $ for a,b>0

If we take x to be a positive coefficient, we get the following result:

$$ e^{-2x} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\left(1\cdot y-xy^{-1}\right)^{2}} dy = e^{-2x} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y^{2}} dy $$

$$ = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} e^{-2x} $$

*And not a single diff eq in sight...*

In all honesty, it is unclear to me how one would tackle this problem using only diff eqs instead of some of the more conventional techniques of integration.

Answer (score 4):

As a differential equation, the intention was probably to notice that

$$f'(x) = -2\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{y^2}e^{-y^2-\frac{x^2}{y^2}}\:dy = -2\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{y^2}-y^2}\:dy = -2f(x)$$

under the variable interchange $y\leftrightarrow \frac{x}{y}$. Thus we have reduced the problem to the initial value problem

$$\begin{cases}f'+2f=0 \\ f(0) = \int_0^\infty e^{-y^2-\frac{0^2}{y^2}}\:dy = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\end{cases}$$