# General form of this integral functional equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-equations

So I was doing some physics and I can recover a variant of the Maxwell distribution (the answer is a gaussian)

$$P(k)dk = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(k-x)P(x) dx dk
$$

I was trying to extend this to the relativistic case. How would one find the general form of this probability distribution $P$? (Is it some kind of Bessel function?)

$$P(k) dk= \int_{0}^\infty P(\lambda)P(k/ \lambda) d \lambda dk
$$

### Edit:

Calculations of the first claim:
$$P(k) dk = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (a^2/ \pi) e^{-a^2(k-x)^2-a^2x^2} dx dk= (a^2/ \pi) \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2 (k^2  - 2x^2 - 2kx)}dx dk =  (a^2/ \pi) \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2 (2(k/2 +x)^2  +k^2/2)}dx dk$$

Taking $x \to k/2 + x$

$$(a^2/ \pi) \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2 (2x^2  +k^2/2)}dx dk= |a| \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}   e^{-a^2k^2/2} dk $$

where $k \to \sqrt2 k$

$$\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{\pi}}   e^{-a^2k^2} dk = P(k) dk$$

Comment: I think you want the last integral to be $$\int_0^\infty(...)\frac{d\lambda}{\lambda}.$$This is scale invariant, just like the first integral is translation invariant.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I double checked it ... It's correct

Comment: A Gaussian is not a solution of the first equation. Delta function is.

Comment: @Andrew I've edited the question to share my calculations ...

Comment: I think , when it comes to this kind of stuff, the idea should be to create a differential equation out of the equation. Also, I believe the calculation has some errors, although I need to look into this more carefully.

Comment: In the exponent it should be $-k^2/2$. A Gaussian (up to a factor) is a probability density of the normal distribution. And the convolution corresponds to a sum of two normal i.e.d., the variance of which is the sum of variances: $1+1=2$.

Comment: And the equation with $dk$ is $P(k/\sqrt 2 )d(k/\sqrt 2 )=C \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(k-x)P(x) dx dk$.

Comment: Just noticed that @Andrew made the point I made in my answer, about similarity to normal r.v. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with previous posters that a Gaussian is not a solution of $P*P=P$, as can be seen easily by working in Fourier space $\hat P \cdot \hat P = \hat P$ can only be solved if $\hat P =1$. Your mistake is precisely where you write $k \to \sqrt2 k$, which means you are replacing $P(k)$ with $P(\sqrt 2 k)$. I suppose you want to say something like $P(x)*P( x)=P(\sqrt 2 x)$. This shouldn't be a surprise since this is an expression for the distribution of the sum of two Gaussian random variables (as @Andrew has pointed out in the comments above).

In order to deal with equations like the second part
$$\int_{0}^\infty P(\lambda)P(k/ \lambda)d\lambda $$, one performs the equivalent of the Fourier transform, but in scale space: the Mellin transform.
$$\int_0^\infty k^\alpha \int_{0}^\infty P(\lambda)P(k/ \lambda)d\lambda dk$$ I wont go into the math, but if you look carefully, you will see that what is going on here is that ${k\over \lambda} = e^{\log(k)-\log(\lambda)}$ so $\log(k),\log(\lambda)$ behave like $k,x$ in the convolution example. Please note that you probably also have a normalization issue in the second integral as well which you should fix, before attempting to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that, in the integral

$$P(k) \; \textrm{d}k = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(k-x)P(x)\; \textrm{d}x\; \textrm{d}k $$

the $\textrm{d}k$ term is really problematic. Wouldn't it be nice if we could just divide both sides by it? Well, if we do, we get the following:

$$P(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(k-x)P(x)\; \textrm{d}x $$

or

$$P(k) = (P*P)(k) $$

In other words, the function $P$ is precisely equal to the convolution of itself with itself!

This implies that $P(k)=0$ or $P(k)=\delta(k)$ for all $k$.

**Edit 1:** I've realized that $1*1$ doesn't really make any sense and just blows up to infinity, so I've replaced the latter equation with $P(k)=\delta(k)$.

**Edit 2:** $P(k)$ cannot be $e^{-k^2}$ because, if it was, then that would imply that $P(k)=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-2k}$ (check out [Find the derivative of the function $f(x)=\int_{0}^\infty e^{-y^2-(x/y)^2} dy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208929/find-the-derivative-of-the-function-fx-int-0-infty-e-y2-x-y2-dy/4213293#4213293)), so you're wrong about that part. And yes, $(P*P)(k)$ returns a Gaussian-type function when $P$ itself is a Gaussian function, but it isn't the same.

**Edit 3:** This is the closest answer you're gonna get, OP. Suppose we have a function,

$$P(k) = \int_0^\infty P(\lambda)P\left(\dfrac{k}{\lambda}\right)\textrm{d}\lambda$$

By the substitution $u=\dfrac{k}{\lambda}$, we obtain the following:

$$P(k) = \int_0^\infty P(u)P\left(\dfrac{k}{u}\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{u^2}\textrm{d}u$$
or
$$P(k) = \int_0^\infty P(\lambda)P\left(\dfrac{k}{\lambda}\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\textrm{d}\lambda$$

Observe that

$$P(k) = \int_0^\infty P(e^{\ln(\lambda)})P\left(e^{\ln(k)-\ln(\lambda)}\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\textrm{d}\lambda$$

Look at the first part of the integral and ignore the second $\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$:

$$\int_0^\infty P(e^{\ln(\lambda)})P\left(e^{\ln(k)-\ln(\lambda)}\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{\lambda}\textrm{d}\lambda$$

Let $u = \ln(\lambda)$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty P(e^{u})P\left(e^{\ln(k)-u}\right)\textrm{d}u$$

Now let $G(k)=P(e^k)$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(u)G\left(\ln(k)-u\right)\textrm{d}u$$

Anyone can easily see that this is equal to

$$(G*G)(\ln(k))$$

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I can even do better than that. Other users have given some nice answers as well, so you should check them out.

Comment: Just seen the edit , and *exactly*, just let me know if you spot an error in the OP's attempt, and we can hopefully rectify this and move on.

Comment: ... to the second equation, I meant.

Answer (score 1):

It is fact that if $f,g\in L^1(\textbf{R})$, then if we define the convolution of $f,g$ as
$$
(f*g)(x)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(x-t)g(t)dt,\tag 1
$$
we have
$$
\widehat{(f*g)}(\gamma)=\widehat{f}(\gamma)\widehat{g}(\gamma),\tag 2
$$
where we have used the notation $\widehat{f}(x):=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}f(t)e^{-it x}dt$.
Hence with no loss of information we can write
$$
P(k)dk=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}P(k-x)P(x)dxdk\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}P(k)e^{-iks}dk=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-iks}\left(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}P(k-x)P(x)dx\right)dk\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}P(k)e^{-iks}dk=\widehat{P}(s)\widehat{P}(s)\Leftrightarrow \widehat{P}(s)=1\Leftrightarrow P(k)=\delta(k),
$$
where $\delta(k)$ is the usual Dirac delta function.

**Remark.**

There are no functions $f,d$ in $L^1(\textbf{R})$, such that $f*d=f$. A more justified answer is in Charles K. Chui:"An introduction to Wavelets". Academic Press. Inc. (Hancourt Brace Jovanovich Publishers) Boston, San Diego, New York, London, Syndney, Tokyo, Toronto. 1992. pg.28

Comment: Surely $\hat{P}(s)^2=\hat{P}(s)$ if and only if $\hat{P}(s)=0$ or $\hat{P}(s)=1$, e.g. if $P$ is an indicator function, giving $P(x)=\int_S e^{ikx}dk$ for a set $S$?

Comment: @JoshuaTilley. No Im asking sorry. Now that you mention, I realise it. For example for  $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\pi x}$, you have $\widehat{f}(w)=\frac{1}{2}(U(w+1)-U(w-1))$, where $U(w)$ is the unit step function. I will search it more and I hope to answer you.

Comment: Another thought: if you wish to restrict $P\in L^1$, then $\hat{P}$ is continuous. So, we do get two solutions, $\hat{P}=0$ and $\hat{P}=1$ identically, in this case. However, the corresponding Dirac delta is not $L^1$!

Comment: By the way, your example $f(x)=\sin x/\pi x$ is given by taking the set $S=[-1,1]$ and computing $\int_Se^{ikx}dk$, i.e. the inverse Fourier transform of the indicator function of $S$, which is your difference of step functions.