# How does one solve these self referential integral equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, integral-equations

So I was doing (my own style of) thermodynamics and ended up with this kind of self-referential integral equation.

\begin{equation}
\label{self ref 2}
     \tilde P(  \lambda) = A \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} (\tilde P (\lambda-x) \tilde P (  x) )^2d( x).\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Is there a standard method of solving these integral equations?

Note the answer for this distribution is:

$$  \tilde P(p_x)  =  A \exp(-p_x^2/2), \tag{2}$$

where $A$ is a normalization constant for the distribution. While, later on I deal with relativity and vectors in $3$ dimensions and things get much more complicated.

Is Mathematica capable of solving this? Is there a standard algorithm to solve this? The more generic algorithm the better?

Comment: If I see this correctly, then the equation is of the type $p(x)=(p*p)(x)$ with $\int_{\Bbb R}p(x)\,dx=1$. Now apply Laplace or Fourier transform theory. But the claimed solution is not among the possible functions.

Comment: You have carefully written your equation so that a seamless change to $p(x)=\tilde P(\tilde β_0 x)$ is possible. Assuming that indeed $\tilde β_0$ is a constant.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4250347/general-form-of-this-integral-functional-equation

Comment: @user619894 there's a square I'd forgotten last time

Comment: 1) as suggested by @LutzLehmann, get rid of the $\tilde \beta_0$. 2) Are you sure the Gaussian solves the integral equation? I think they can't all have the same variance.

Comment: @user619894 a. LutzmanLehmann was responding to a previous version (but sure) and b. yes -
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+from+-infinity+to+infinity+%28e%5E%28%28-%28y-x%29%5E2%29%2F2%29+%28e%5E%28%28-%28x%29%5E2%29%2F2%29%29%29%5E2+dx

Comment: Regarding point 2, you are correct, I misread the square term.